# How to pull values from a dictionary with duplicate keys

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I'm working on a text-based adventure game where the player moves between rooms and collects items. 'items' is a duplicate key. When I run my program, it's pulling the last value of 'item', instead of the one that pairs to the location. Here is my code:

```py
#Stephanie Rivera

rooms = {
    'Foyer': {'North': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Pocket Watch', 'East': 'Library', 'item': 'Diary Page'},
    'Library': {'West': 'Foyer'},
    'Kitchen': {'West': 'Living Room', 'item': 'Ripped Photo', 'East': 'Bedroom',
                'North': 'Turret', 'South': 'Foyer'},
    'Living Room': {'East': 'Kitchen'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Attic', 'item': 'The Shadow Man', 'West': 'Kitchen'},
    'Attic': {'South': 'Bedroom', 'item': 'Book of Matches'},
    'Turret': {'East': 'Cellar', 'item': 'Ouija Board', 'South': 'Kitchen'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Turret', 'item': 'Lantern'}
    }

print('Welcome to The Shadow Man Text Adventure Game.')
print('Collect 6 items to win the game, or be defeated by The Shadow Man.')
print('Move commands: North, South, East, West.')
print("To add items to inventory, enter: Get 'item'.")

location = 'Foyer'
inventory = []
player_move = ''
item = ''


def show_instructions():
    #print instructions
    print('You are in the', location)
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print('___________')


def player_location():
    #print player's location on the map
    print('You are in the', location)

def player_inventory():
    #print player's inventory
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    print('___________')

def player_input():
    print('Enter a move:')
    player_move = input()

show_instructions()

print('You are lost in the woods. You see a house with a light on up ahead. You decide to enter the house.')

while len(inventory) < 6:
    player_move = input('Enter a move: ' )
    for k in rooms[location].keys():
        if player_move == k:
            value = [rooms[location].get('item')[]]
            location = rooms[location][player_move]
            player_location()
            print('You see a', *value)
            player_input()
```

Comment: You don't. Its **impossible** for a dictionary to contain duplicate keys. When you create the dictionary, only one of those will actually exist - the other one(s) get overwritten as key-value pairs are added. You have to design your keys to have no duplicates. Make a key `items`, and make its value a list of the items.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Sorry, the "Make a key `items`" mislead me. Will remove my previous comment.

Comment: Here is an example, to be clearer. Make a key `"items"`. Make the value stored at that key a list of items. `'items' : ['Pocket Watch','Diary Page']`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there cannot be duplicate keys in a dictionary.

So, if you want to store multiple values, use a list and keep appending to that list.

```
rooms = {
    ...
    ...
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Turret', 'item': ['Lantern', 'Book', 'blah', 'blah']}
}
```